# How to combine multibib package and thebibliography environment?

Tags: bibtex, citing, multibib

I want to two thebibliography environments in my latex document. I want to put one of them as a reference for the main text and another one of them as a reference for supplemental material of the document. It seems that multibib package is the most promising method that can achieve this. But I want to know if it is possible to use multibib package and thebibliography environment since I see most of the tutorials I can find online use multibib package and `\bibliography` command, e.g. [this one](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Creating_multiple_bibliographies_in_the_same_document#Packages_for_BibTeX)?

Comment: Usually you don't need `multibib`, if you use two or more manually made `thebibliography` environments — at least, if you use the optional argument of `\bibitem`. So please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) of what you've tried and which makes your problem reproducible.

Comment: On the other hand using either `\bibliography` and BibTeX or `biblatex` and `biber` would be generally recommended. It may seem, that it is more complicated. But at the time, you want to change an existing bibliography, you will see, that it is efficiently. `biblatex` supports multiple bibliographies out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the `references` environment.